# Can I choose which kind of items are in the boxes?

Tags: mario-kart-8-deluxe

I remember that in Mario Kart Wii, there was some kind of item settings. The items were divided between aggressive items (shells, bloopers, pows, etc.) and strategic items (mushrooms, stars, bullets), and you could choose if you wanted all items, only one of the categories, or none at all.

Is there such a setting in this version? If so, where do I find it? I'm particularly interested in local multiplayer, where disabling the overly troublesome items (*cough* blue shell *cough*) might help with the overall mood of everyone after a few races.

Comment: On the WiiU version you could set custom games where you specified which items were enabled and which were disabled. I can't really guide you exactly where that option is, as I don't have a WiiU anymore and I don't have MK8D on Switch, but the custom race option was pretty obvious, iirc.

Answer (score 2):

On Mario Kart 8 Deluxe you can choose between six settings for items. They are Shells only, Bananas only, Mushrooms only and Bob - ombs only. Then there is All items, No items and Frantic items.

Comment: Great! How do I do that?

Comment: @Kareen You go into the rules for your custom match. From there, there should be an option to change the items.

Comment: Isn't there also one labelled "Frantic Items"?

Comment: @BlueBarren Not from what I've seen.

Comment: @Elizer [are you sure?](http://i.imgur.com/IletwpV.jpg)

Comment: @BlueBarren Oh. I never saw that in my research. Thank you for pointing that out. I will edit my answer to include that.